# Grails: Eager fetching of one-to-manies

Tags: grails

While reading about the [GORM Gotchas](http://spring.io/blog/2010/07/28/gorm-gotchas-part-3/) I am a bit confused about eager fetching of one-to-manies. Whereas it is stated at the aforementioned link:

> consider this query:
>
> `Author.list(max: 2, fetch: [ books: 'join' ])`
>
> In all likelihood, this will return only one Author instance. That’s
>   probably not the behaviour you expect or want. So what’s happening?
>
> **Under the hood Hibernate is using a left outer join to fetch the books
>   for each author. That means you get duplicate Author instances: one
>   for each book the author is associated with.** If you don’t have the max
>   option there, you won’t see those duplicates because GORM removes
>   them. But the trouble is the max option is applied to the result
>   before the duplicates are removed. So in the example above, Hibernate
>   only returns two results, both of which are likely to have the same
>   author. GORM then removes the duplicate and you end up with a single
>   Author instance.

The bolded portion of the above quote is where my confusion begins.If it is a left outer join shouldn't we end up getting books that are solely by every author(books only by one author) and not books that are by more than one author (the intersection of the sets which we don't get in a left outer join)? Or is this implying something about the treatment of books that maybe by more than one author by the `[ books: 'join']` query modifier.

I'd be much obliged for any clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion comes from your not understanding the SQL that is being executed using a `LEFT JOIN` to fetch the list of books. What the comment is trying to point out is that by using a `LEFT JOIN` the `MAX` gives you unexpected results. Consider the following

```
author
id, name
1, Bob
2, Joe

book
id, name
1, First book
2, Second book
3, Third book
4, Fourth book

author_books
author_id, book_id
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
2, 4
```

The query uses a `LEFT JOIN` when fetching the Author and it's Book association so the data being returned from the database looks like this:

```
author.id, author.name, book.id, book.name
1, Bob, 1, First book
1, Bob, 2, Second book
```

This will result in a single author being returned but the collection of books will only include two of the three associated books. This is due to the `MAX` restriction being applied to the SQL statement itself and limiting the maximum number of rows returned.

The reason why this is pointed out is because you **might** expect that you'd get a maximum of two Authors in your list regardless of the number of associated books, but because of the fetch mode that's not the case because of the actual SQL that is being executed.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @JosuaMoore Yes, that does help. Thanks for providing such a detailed and insightful answer. You were perfectly right in that it was my lack of SQL understanding impeding my thinking. Thanks again.

Comment: Upon trying this exercise with the data set you demonstrated in your answer, whether I give the `max: 2` option to the `list()` method or not, I get the expected results (meaning 2 author instances). I am not running to the problem that is discussed in my question(only one author instance returned). Is that because it won't necessarily occur? Meaning it's likely but not 100 percent going to happen?

Comment: I assume that's including the fetch mode in your `list()`? The fetch mode is central to this issue with max.

Comment: I tried the query just like in my original question. Meaning via a query rather than domain class static mapping modifier.

Comment: Yes, with the `join` fetch mode.

Comment: I'd recommend turning on SQL logging and watching the SQL statements then.

Comment: I'm far from an SQL expert but I did do this because I was curious. See the results if you like. Here is the query as usual with the 'max: 2' option: http://snag.gy/1Bwpo.jpg then here it is with no 'max: 2 option': http://snag.gy/dmGh1.jpg. See how my results are the same in both cases? I am not running into the problem posed in the original post. The solution to which nevertheless is to use the 'select' fetch mode which I did try anyway here: http://snag.gy/WMuRB.jpg.

Comment: I had Peter Ledbrook take a look at this post and here is his response and I just thought you might like to know. `I think that particular behaviour was fixed, either in GORM or Hibernate. I suspect the ordering of the LIMIT and grouping was reversed. I guess some of the stuff in GORM Gotchas no longer applies. Remember that the series was written against some old versions of Grails`